# Using the // operator in JXPath

Tags: java, xpath, data-structures, tree, jxpath

Some root object has field `MyCollection myCollection`. The class `MyCollection` implements `Collection` interface. The names of elements are available by calling `someService().getName()` that's why I created `Rules` class.

`context.getValue("/myCollection");`
returns myCollection - OK

`context.getValue("//myCollection");`
returns myCollection - OK

`context.getValue("/myCollection/.[rules:getName() = 'secondName']");`
returns the instance of `IMyNode` which `someService().getName()` returns 
"secondName" - OK

After line
`context.getValue("/myCollection//.[rules:getName() = 'secondName']");`
the next lines are NOT executed. Also no exception, and lenient mode is 
not set. I do not understand what is going on.
Line 8. of `Rules` class prints `"POINTER SET ON /myCollection[1]"`. The element which I want to get in this example is in `/myCollection[2]`.

This is the where the name of element is get. I think that this class is correct.

```
public class Rules {
public static String getName(ExpressionContext context){
   Pointer pointer = context.getContextNodePointer();
    if(pointer == null){
        return "";
    } else {
        if(pointer.getValue() instanceof IMyNode){
        System.out.println("POINTER SET ON " + pointer);
            IMyNode node = (IMyNode)pointer.getValue();
           return node.someService().getName();
       }
   }
   return "";
}
}
```

**EDIT:**
This question is about **JXPath**. I was wrong with adding tag xpath instead of jxpath.

Comment: You *forgot* to give us something important: a sample source XML document.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `*` instead of `.`. Also I think you can use standard XPath function `local-name()` instead of `rules:getName()`.

Comment: `"/myCollection/*[rules:getName() = 'secondName']"` causes `org.apache.commons.jxpath.JXPathNotFoundException: No value for xpath: /myCollection/*[rules:getName() = 'secondName']`. With `//` operator, it still hangs. I can not use `local-name()` because as I wrote, the name of node is available by calling `node.someService().getName()`. This is the tree structure of some complex objects.  I'm not sure, but maybe this is important. `MyCollection` apart from this that it is a collection, also has many different others attributes.